# Objective-C Model-View communication

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class of which an instance is created when a UIViewController is loaded. I need the instance of this class to be able to update the ViewController when certain events happen. This is how I have accomplished this:

AViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progress;
@Property (strong, nonatomic) ClassB *classB
-(void)incrementProgressBar: (NSNumber *)currentProgress;
```

AViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    _classB = [ClassB alloc]initWithNonReleventVariable:variable];
    [_classB setInstanceViewController:self]
}
-(void)incrementProgressBaar: (NSNumber *)currentProgress;
{
    [_progressBar setProgress:[currentProgrsss floatValue] animated:YES];
}
```

ClassB.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)AViewController *avc;
@property (nonatomic) double progress;
```

ClassB.m

```
-(void)incrementExerciseProgress
{
    //do some calculations here
    [self.avc incremtProgressBar:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:_progress]];
}
```

I inherited this code from someone else and it works properly. So my question is this: Is this a "correct" way to accomplish this? I want to know if this is best practice? or if not what I could do to fix it so it was. I have some time on this project so I want to make sure I do it correctly if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you've created an ARC Strong Reference Cycle here.  `classB` points strongly to `avc`, which points strongly to `classB`.  This creates a memory leak and will likely cause unintended behavior.  One of those two properties should be `weak`, not `strong` in order to avoid this cycle.

Comment: @AaronBrager You're right. I have fixed that. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way, introduced high coupling between two classes from two different layers. You can instead create a `ClassBDelegate` protocol.

```
@protocol ClassBDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) classB: (ClassB *)class hasIncrementedProgressTo:(NSNumnber *)prgoress;
@end
```

Make `AViewController` conform to it. This way, `ClassB` can neglect any changes in the controller layer. An instance of `ClassB` only needs to inform its delegate of the changes in raw data and the it's the delegate's job, i.e the view controller, to show that change using views.

Comment: Just to say that a delegate is a good solution but you could do the same with a block or even posting a notification(although the notification does not fit as good in this case).

Comment: There are many ways to reduce coupling between objects. But I guess that delegation is the best solution in this case. Blocks are good too, but they would be more suitable as callback to some method: `[object doSomethingWithCallBack:^(BOOL flag){....}]`. But as a way to  handle general events of an object, I prefer delegation.

Comment: I've used Delegates before and this makes sense, but I am going to look into callbacks and blocks as well. thanks.

Comment: I decided to go with answer because it made sense for this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They can share a mutable data structure (for example a NSMutableDictionary) that is affected by the events of the View, and let the other class be notified by KVO of this change, so they're totally decoupled by datastructures.

The KVO part could be improved by the MAKVONotificationCenter library :)

If you requiere an example let me know

Greetings

Luis Alejandro

Ref:

- [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/)
- [MAKVONotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/)

Comment: This is interesting. I'm going to take the time to look into it more deeply, since I've never heard of KVO before now.